# Trying to get the Job # Column to auto-sort

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to get column range B4:B800 to auto-sort after a new job # is added from the Job Creation macro I have.  However, it seems to automatically move other rows that are intended to stay put.

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4:B800")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B4").Sort Key1:=Range("B5"), _
          Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _    
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```

I attempted to change Header:=xlYes to Header:=xlNo but then it would not even sort anything at that point.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes the easiest way to find what code you want is to just record yourself doing it manually then adapting the resulting macro.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: You can use an intelligent list or in VBA a listobject. Mark the range you want to convert into an intelligent list/listobject and press "CTRL"+"L". One of the advantages of an intelligent list, that you don't have to change your code if you move the list within the current worksheet.

In the menue will appear a new tab where you can name your intelligent list. I recommend to you to use the macro recorder to get some vba code for your task.

I've done an example with your given data and called the intelligent list "lstJobs". Here is the code for you. Keep in mind to optimize this code for your specific task.

I've also changed the codename of the table, where the list is set, to "MyWorksheet".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngJobs As Range
    
'Set the column which should be sorted and also where the selected cell has to be to start your code

    Set rngJobs = MyWorksheet.Range("lstJobs[[#All],[Job'#]]")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngJobs) Is Nothing Then
    
        With MyWorksheet.ListObjects("lstJobs").Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add _
                Key:=rngJobs, _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlAscending, _
                DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```